# firebase message IOS

Tags: firebase, react-native

I setup react-native firebase message, for push notification on IOS.
in DEV env work OK,
but in rl env can't push,
For error checking, there is a message as shown below,
As far as I understand, it is not generating the token
I have cert push for DEV and PRO

```
react native version: 0.63.4
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^10.8.1",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.8.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.8.1",
```

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sthd7.png

Comment: Somebody help me, many thank

Comment: you need to provide a translation on the error, it's in an unknown language

Comment: XCode response Vietnamese message, the error is "Not found cert aps-environment valid for application "

Comment: did you create a production key in the apple developer page?

Comment: yes, i have key,

Answer (score 0):

I found problem, inside project, file ${projectname}.entitlements don't have key.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnJdu.png)